PHP Laravel pagination links remembering pagination
How to make laravel pagination $couriers->links() remember pagination size? It always sets back to default 1 because the url by $couriers->links() does not include values other than page.
class CourierController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index(Request $request){
        // Get the sort option from the request, default to sorting by 'id'
        $sortField = $request->input('sort', 'id');
        $sortOrder = $request->input('order', 'asc'); // 'asc' or 'desc'
        $pagination = $request->input('pagination', 1);

        // Fetch and sort the couriers
        $couriers = Courier::orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder)->paginate($pagination);
        return view("main", compact("couriers", 'sortField', 'sortOrder', 'pagination'));
    }
    public function sort(Request $request)
    {
        $sortField = $request->input('sort', 'id');
        $sortOrder = $request->input('order', 'asc');
        $pagination = $request->input('pagination', 1);
        $couriers = Courier::orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder)->paginate($pagination);
        return response()->json($couriers);
    }
}

I tried using variables inside class but apparently the class recreates every time or so, they anyway set back to init values. Do I have to write the pagination links by myself then?

why are you not using page as the query param?

remember pagination size? It always sets back to default 1 - so are you trying to remember page size or the page?

Does this answer your question? Pagination + URL Params in Laravel 7
